# Troubleshooting tcp connection over wireless network

Tags: ruby, windows, networking, tcp

I have two Windows computers on my home network that can't seem to communicate over a client/server TCP connection that I am testing.

Here is a simple Ruby server that I am running on a Windows Server 2008 box:

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open(2000)

puts "Server started"

loop {
  client = server.accept
  client.puts "Hello client"
  client.close
}

puts "Server stopped"
```

Here is a simple client that I am running on a Windows 7 box:

```
require 'socket'

hostname='192.168.1.10'
port=2000

s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port)

while line = s.gets
  puts line.chop
end
s.close
```

When the server is running, and I run the client I see this error:

client.rb:6:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (Er
rno::ETIMEDOUT)

I have created an exception on the server's firewall for port 2000 so that it will allow any device to connect (I've even tried turning off the firewall entirely).

I also think the code itself is fine because I can establish a connection successfully when I run the client from the same box as the server.

I think there is something blocking the network connection, but I'm not well versed at troubleshooting network issues, so where should I start to figure this out?

Comment: I ended up changing the server's code from TCPServer.open(2000) to TCPServer.new(2000).  I can't explain to you the difference, but this made it work.